# Rotation won't work in firemonkey android app when clipchidren is active

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to rotate a TRectangle in Delphi 10.3.3. (FireMonkey App)
the Trectangle has ClipChildren set to true.
The rotation works fine in win32 but when trying in android it has a weird clipped shape.
I tried it with different Objects(TPanel,TImage & ... ) and all results same.
It seems that there is a bug with rotating shapes and clipchildren property in android.
Here is a sample fmx file which works fine in win32 platform but not in ANDROID.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 329
  ClientWidth = 259
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    ClipChildren = True
    Fill.Color = claChartreuse
    Position.X = 80.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 104.000000000000000000
    RotationAngle = 35.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 105.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 113.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
end
```

Best regards,

mohsen

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because on android you use GPU canvas that is a bit different from the default windows canvas. Under GPU canvas rotation and clipchildren simply not work together. I will not say it's a bug, rather than it's the way its work

Comment: thank you. it means that it didn't implemented correctly so it is a bug :)